# Prime element of a quadratic integer ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, quadratic-integer-rings

For simplicity, let $D$ be a square-free integer such that $D\equiv 2,3 \pmod 4$ such that the class number of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}]$ is 1.

> -Theorem in the page for "quadratic integer rings" in **[oeis](http://oeis.org/wiki/Quadratic_integer_rings)**
>
> Let $p$ be a prime element of $\mathbb{Z}$.
>
> If $p$ is not a prime element of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}]$, then there exist two primes $\pi,\pi'$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}]$ such that $p=\pi\pi'$.

How do I prove this? And is this theorem really a theorem? Actually I doubt this theorem.

Since $p$ is not prime in the quadratic integer ring, there are elements $a,b$ such that $p|ab$ and $p$ does not divide both $a$ and $b$. And I think this condition is too weak to imply the existence of such $\pi$ and $\pi'$.

I have rather proven that "if $p$ is not irreducible, then there are two irreducibles such that $p=\pi\pi'$". Moreover, I have shown that the above theorem is true in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$, but I doubt the case $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}]$.

If that theorem is really true, how do I prove it? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: $\pi$ and $\pi'$ are supposed to be ideals in this theorem. Then it is true.

Comment: @MooS I don't get you.. I wrote $\pi$ to mean an element, but what do you mean change an element to an ideal?

Comment: In the general case the theorem is indeed false, if $\pi, \pi'$ are supposed to be elements of the ring. I gave a counterexample in the comments below.

Comment: @MooS I get it. Thank you :)

Comment: Please edit the question to state that the ring is a UFD if this is what is intended (else it will confuse many future readers too).

Comment: @BillDubuque Actually I did mean what was written in my post. I posted this question since I misread the article which assumes the ring to be UFD. Anyway, I edited :)

Comment: Yes, I know. If would be better if your edit looked like "update: the ring is assumed to be a UFD on said page. This hypothesis was not originally in my question...". Then readers can make sense of the comments, etc. Otherwise, again, readers may waste time attempting to figure out what the prior comments mean, and/or needlessly replying to them, thinking them wrong, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt D]$ is a UFD.

If $p$ isn't prime in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt D]$ there is $\pi\in\mathbb Z[\sqrt D]$ prime such that $p=\pi\pi'$, $\pi'\in\mathbb Z[\sqrt D]$. Now use the norm and find that $N(\pi')=\pm p$, so $\pi'$ is prime.

Comment: This is false. The theorem is not true, if $\pi$ is supposed to be an element of the ring. It has to be an ideal. Consider $3 \in \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$. $3$ is not prime, but there is no decomposition of the element $3$ into other elements. You have to decompose the ideal.

Comment: There is not a single reason to assume this.

Comment: @user26857 So you are assuming UFD to make $p$ reducible, which is what I proved already.. So the theorem stated itself is wrong? Moreover, I checked Theorem 9.29, but it is a theorem in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$, not the quadratic integer ring.

Comment: If the OP does only consider quadratic integer rings with class number $1$, he should really state this in his first question...

Comment: @MooS You are right, but I just realized that I misread the oeis article.. It was there assumed the rings to have class number 1. I'm sorry.. So I guess the statement in my question is in general false.